# android use smack api with facebook chat

Tags: android, facebook, smack

hi im trying to use the smack api to send/receive messages in facebook chat. im using:

```
host: chat.facebook.com
port: 5222
service: chat.facebook.com
username: my facebook username@chat.facebook.com
password: my facebook password
```

logcat says im getting a "503 service unavailable error" but i cant work out why. my username/password work when logging into the facebook website, and the smack api works when using google talk, but it wont let me log in to chat.facebook.com (allthough it seems to connect to the server fine). any ideas on whats wrong?

cheers for any help,
ng93

Comment: did it work via http://code.google.com/p/asmack/downloads/list.i am using same still getting service unavailable error

Answer (score 1):

Smack 3.0.3 Working fine. get these jar's
http://hostfile.org/smack_3_0_3.zip